# DOCSIS 3.1 vs. 3.0 and streaming

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router

I plan on 'cutting the cord' next week and registering a Playstation Vue account. We currently have internet only from Comcast Xfinity, with the Blast! speeds. Even with said Blast! speed, we still have buffering issues watching Netflix and Amazon video (both over wifi). I also just purchased a Netgear Nighthawk 1900 DOCSIS 3.0 modem/router combo with voice. I am setting it up today. Will this help with the buffering (replacing Comcast standard box) or should I upgrade to a 3.1 modem/router combo? I have a hard-wired PC, a PC on wifi, a couple smart phones, a couple Google Chromecast and Amazon Fire TV (buffering). Any suggestions are appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: Well what did you have before the DOCSIS 3.0 one? 3.0 to 3.1 does have quite a big jump for increase but it is up to you for the cost standpoint. Helpful article: https://blogs.cisco.com/sp/the-benefits-of-docsis-3-1

Comment: Unless your current modem is defective, replacing a 3.0 modem with a 3.1 modem will not fix a buffering issues. The problem is bigger than that... Breakdown the issues piece by piece to find the problem, connect a laptop hard wired directly to modem, is it good? Is it a wireless issue? etc... The information you have given is not sufficient to formulate a definitive answer.

Comment: Frankly, if you didn't diagnose the source of the problem in your old setup, what use can there be for asking for opinions on two possible replacement setups? We can't know if it'll solve your problem unless we know where the problem is. Maybe the problem is that Comcast's CMTS for your neighborhood is overloaded and nothing you can do in your house will solve the buffering problem.

Comment: While I agree with spiff here, there are some things you can check. Check the Modem logs & signal to noise ratios reported by the modem. Looking for T3 dropouts / critical errors in the log. Look for excessively low SNR on the downstream, and excessively high SNR on the upstream. Does this issue happen from wired Ethernet connections? If it doesn't it's probably just interference on the wifi channel your router is on. Regards,

Comment: Thank you everybody! The one I have now is Comcast's Arris 1682G router/modem combo. My PC is hardwired and is usually pretty fast. The wifi for our smartphones is good. The only real problem we have is the wifi/signal to the main TV. It's a Sony SmartTV and it's about 40' away from my router/modem. I have an Amazon Fire TV connected to it.

Comment: Add another router in Ap-mode to the network. It's probably a combination of low RSSI from your first router mixed with interference from neighboring routers on the same channel. Try switching the channel to either 1, 6, or 11 first

Comment: Hi Tim, thanks. I'm not sure what you mean by switching channels. I'm not very knowledgeable with this stuff.

Comment: Log into the router, go to the wireless settings. You should have a setting for the wireless channel your WiFi is operating on. You should be able to switch to another that may give you better performance. If it's too far away, add another access point. But trying switching the channels first.